# Redirect using spring ldap login page causes extra url path which is incorrect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

If I am using spring security to connect to ldap when I connect lets say to the url: www.serverAdress/myapp/

I should be redirected to 
www.serverAdress/myapp/login

but instead I am redirected to 
www.serverAddress/myappmyapp/login

I am not sure how the extra myapp is added it is also obtained if a redirect is used within the return of the views.

Edit added the configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin();





}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain", "ldap://url", "rootDN custom");







    authenticationProvider.setSearchFilter("customfilter");

    authenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    authenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);


    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

}

Comment: youll need to post config - but does your form-login contains the myapp in login-page?

Comment: @farrellmr I am not using any custom login page I am using the normal login page. but which config do you need?

Comment: your spring security config

Comment: @farrellmr I have added the config above

Comment: Add .loginPage to yoru login page

Comment: @farrellmr this does not solve the problem of the redirect adding this extra information that will cause more problems if we get redirected to the result?